# Odoo 14 on Apache2 Reverse Proxy - Pagespeed errors consistently

Tags: odoo, nginx-reverse-proxy, apache2.4, mod-pagespeed, odoo-14

I am encountering pagespeed errors consistently in an SSL environment. The problem occurs on all SSL environments we create. We are using Apache2 as a reverse proxy. This is working well; however, Pagespeed errors occur (whether or not pagespeed is active in apache2) usually when scrolling through WEB pages it will trigger.

We are using Odoo 14 CE and our specs for the server are great. 3+gb of memory with 2vCpu's on a GCP instance.

The most common error that we see is:

```
ReferenceError: pagespeed is not defined

https://example.com/:1

Traceback:

onload@https://example.com/:1:1
```

This occurs on every page on our website. We have disabled Pagespeed in apache2 but the errors still occur. Now we are thinking we should install the mod_pagespeed module and would like to know if someone has successfully achieved pagespeed with Apache2 as a reverse proxy.

Note that once the pagespeed error flags, things like copy/paste via Ctrl+C/P also start to trigger pagespeed error's making it extremely difficult and at times impossible to edit pages effectively.

Please advise.

> Update on Nginx
> Have tested this now with Nginx 1.18.0 and latest stable pagespeed. The system error's out with Pagespeed in the same fashion on this build also.

Will add additional information as it presents itself.

Moving too fast through a single page seems to be what causes the initial flag. PageSpeed turned off does the same. In both Apache 2.4 and Nginx 1.18.0 (with Pagespeed ON or OFF).

This does not seem to ever happen on the backend, have checked Sales, Invoicing, etc and no PageSpeed errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it after trying many things for several hours.
Disabling pagespeed by itself doesnt work.

1. First uninstall website app in odoo (will erase all your site)
2. Disable Pagespeed
3. Install website app
4. Start building your site again
5. There is only 1 error I got, when trying to edit HTML,  that I fixed in postgres.

Hope.you dont have a huge site

Comment: I use bitnami Odoo 14 CE in a GCP instance